# Is there some place to download an AIX mod_jk binary?

Tags: apache, tomcat, aix, binaries

I needed to front tomcat with apache on AIX, but there is nothing in http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/aix and googling around was unsuccessful. I eventually built it from source (painful as there is bureaucracy around getting the compilers installed at this large corporate).

But shouldn't this binary download exist somewhere? Why do they just have an empty directory?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that they don't have an AIX or FreeBSD (also not there) machine around to do it.  Perhaps you could volunteer your build?

Answer (score 1):

AIX is not the only neglected platform.

General interrest and support for the mod_jk project seems to have diminished since the introduction of mod_proxy_ajp into the main source of apache-2.2

This modules performes basically the same functionality as mod_jk and does not need an extra install.

The version of apache-2.2 I got from http://gnome.bullfreeware.com/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/apache/ also contains this module.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to get the binary and not compile it? You can get all the source from apache's svn.